# POSIX IPC linker error in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, ubuntu, linker, eclipse-cdt

I´m going to implement a IPC library, using the POSIX API. ( Ubuntu / Eclipse CDT )
Unfortunately I´m having Linker errors. The library should be available because Linux supports POSIX message queues since kernel 2.6.6.

```
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
...

msgq_id = mq_open("/queueName", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG, NULL);
```

when it invokes the GCC C++ Linker it ends up in "undefined reference to `mq_open' "

I think it could be a general Linux configuration Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had some issues using Eclipse CDT as well. I solved this by setting up a cmake project to be independent from the eclipse configurations.

A good point to start is the [tutorial section](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) from [cmake.org](http://www.cmake.org)

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and this worked for me:

In the Eclipse project properties/C/C++ General/ Paths and Symbols , under Libraries click on Add and type "rt" (no quotes).
This should tell it to include -lrt when building which is required when using POSIX queues.